# Start SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013 using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, javascript, designer-workflow

How to start SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow using Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2013 provides set of JavaScript libraries that can be used to manage workflows. First, you need to refer sp.workflowservices.js which is available in _layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js.

```
 <script src="/_layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js"></script>
```

you can use the below code to start your list workflow(s)

```
   function startWF(itemID, listId) {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var workflowServiceManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
        var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
        var subscriptions = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(listId);
        //run all workflows associated with the list
        context.load(subscription);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            foreach(var workflowSubscription in subscriptions)
            {
                var inputParameters = {};
                workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService().StartWorkflowOnListItem(workflowSubscription, itemId, inputParameters);
            }
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onStartSucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onStartFailed));
        },
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onLoadFailed)
          );

    }

    function onStartSucceeded(sender, args) {
        alert("Workflow Started Successfully.");
    }

    function onStartFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Workflow Initiation Failed  ' + args.get_message() +
       '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    function onLoadFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```